# How to properly define types for a decorator that injects props in a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to build a decorator that injects on decorated components some props from a React Context, I've had many problems defining the type signature for the decorator itself, as the decorator call, implementation and decorated component usage would always give one error.

This is my latest approach:

The decorator:

```
type ContextType = {
  pageContext: {
    language: string;
  };
};

const PageContext = React.createContext({
  pageContext: {
    language: 'en-US',
  },
  // there are more keys than pageContext
});

export function withPageContext<P>(WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<P>) {
  return (props: Omit<P, keyof ContextType>) => (
    <PageContext.Consumer>
      {(consumerProps: ContextType) => <WrappedComponent {...consumerProps} {...props} />}
    </PageContext.Consumer>
  );
}
```

The `withPageContext` call gives no errors and the decorated components have the right props.
But the decorator implementation gives the following TypeScript error on the `<WrappedComponent ... />` call:

```
Type '{ pageContext: { language: string; }; } & Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "pageContext">>' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.


  Type '{ pageContext: { language: string; }; } & Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "pageContext">>' is not assignable to type 'P'.


    '{ pageContext: { language: string; }; } & Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, "pageContext">>' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.ts(2322)
```

Which I'm having a hard deciphering.

The error goes away if I change the `Omit<P, keyof ContextType>` to just `P` but the decorated components now complain that they are missing the injected props...

So any help with this would be appreciated, maybe my entire idea behind the `Omit<P, keyof...` is wrong after all

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you want to use the `PageContext` in a component, you can simply call `useContext(PageContext)` inside that component. Is there any benefit to creating a decorator? And will the wrapped component ever be rendered without this decorator?

Comment: I think that i cannot use `useContext` in a class component method, and no, the component will not be rendered without the decorator, but multiple components depend on this context, so id like to extract it to a decorator so i dont need too write much boilerplate

Comment: Have you tried converting your class components to function components? Then the only 'boilerplate' you need is `useContext(PageContext)` inside the component.

Comment: I guess i could? but here is the problem, we are using class components for a reason, they have may getters, and methods, and if I would need to convert all of them to class components, I would prefer to add the `useContext` on the caller of the component. So there is no way I can type this decorator properly? I'm asking this question because im having similar problems with other decorators that inject props as well, not just this one that injects a context, this is just the smallest example i have.